# How can I make Bash save unrecognized commands to a file?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

How is Bash simple one line syntax to check and get the invalid or unrecognized command fed in shell or terminal prompt to be saved in a file? Illustration e.g.

```
$ run_bash_command FILE

$ foo
bash: foo: command not found

$ bar
bash: bar: command not found

$ baz
bash: baz: command not found

$ cat FILE
foo
bar
baz
```

Comment: Did you check ~/.bash_history ?

Comment: @WeDBA `.bash_history` only contains the commands, not whether they were unrecognized or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash version >= 4.0 I suggest to add this function to `~/.bashrc` and start a new session:

```
command_not_found_handle() {
  echo "bash: $1: command not found" >&2;
  echo "$@" >> /tmp/file.txt;
}
```